# SSH in vscode, python runner is not working

Tags: python, vscode-remote

I am able to run the code with terminal by python3 test.py...

The runner button is showing up but when I press it, nothing really happens.

Also, python code does not show any color.

I uninstalled the python extension and re-installed.

I even intalled the previous version of python.

but nothing changed.

Any advice?

[image]